# Python function import

Tags: python

```
game_data = {}

def data_add(x):
    game_data[x.__name__] = x
    
game_name = "notyet"

data_add(game_name)
print(game_data)
```

> ```
> { AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
> ```

I want `{'game_name'= 'notyet'}`

Comment: What you want won't be possible.  There's nothing in the Python data model that associates a variable name with an object outside of the scope where you are using the variable name.

Comment: @MarkRansom Probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behavior you want with a little added redundancy:

```
game_data = {}

def data_add(**params):
    (key, value) = (list)(params.items())[0]
    game_data[key] = value


game_name = "notyet"

data_add(game_name=game_name)
print(game_data)
```

Result:

```
{'game_name': 'notyet'}
```

The capability is the same.  No abstraction is lost.  If you can type the variable name once, you can type it twice.

There's likely a better way to do whatever you really want to accomplish with this pattern.  Using the name of a variable like this is not a good practice.  Variables hold data.  Variables aren't themselves data.

Why not just do:

```
game_data = {}

def data_add(key, value):
    game_data[key] = value

data_add("game_name", "notyet")
print(game_data)
```

Another option, which will give you the exact call to `data_add` that you want, is to associate the name with the value as a tuple that then can be passed in as a single positional parameter:

```
game_data = {}

def data_add(x):
    game_data[x[0]] = x[1]

game_name = ("game_name", "notyet")

data_add(game_name)
print(game_data)
```

Comment: i want import with one key like 
'add(value)' .it's must be value = "value".

Comment: Well, as @MarkRansom points out, what you want isn't possible.